# CDN module - serving files from subdomain - setup

Tags: cdn

Can plaease somebody point me to correct setup if I want my files to be served from subdomain?

As I understood I should choose origin pull mode.
Then create a subdomain.
Copy all files inside same structure to new subdomain.
In config details of CDN module add new subdomain

Should I add some rules inside htaccess of new subdomain?
Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Amazon Cloudfront - You are using origin pull cdn in which case you can:

1. Create an custom origin in there service 
   http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-custom-origins.html
2. Point that url that you get from cloudfront to a cname in your dns info in you admin panel in hosting setup
3. Install the cdn module enable it select origin pull and add the mapping the for files

Then save and you should be good to go

If you wanted to make an attempt at file conveyor that can be found here

http://fileconveyor.org/

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific - I want to create subdomain on my own domain xxx.com like media.xxx.com and pull files from there.

Comment: yeah all would do is sign up for amazon web services and open a cloudfront account use a custom origin and then create a cname of your choice and then point that cname to the cloundfront url and then that should work do you know how to create a cname ? who is your hosting provider ?

Comment: Oh I understand now, so the account on amazon must be used even I want to share files from my own subdomain. But it is paid as I can see. I there any non paid solution? My provider is a local company in my country - none of the big ones in world:)